# JS files not loading on Android Chrome but load on Windows Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am developing a website for mobile users.

What I'm facing now is that Google Chrome for Android (i.e the Google Chrome Android app) does not run my JS files.

http://development.mysite.com/js/test.js

I have not idea why it's not loading my JS files.

I have tried ( http://development.mysite.com/js/test.js?v=< echo $time; ?> ), using PHP to echo unique times but still did not work.

Please can someone help me on this, does it have to do with content security policy?

Comment: Debug the script remotely from your PC: [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve this problem, i noticed if the script tag is not in the header section,

e.g

```
<body>
    <script src="this_js_src.js"></script>
</body>
```

Google chrome and firefox would not run or load the above script source.
I moved all script to the header section

```
<head>
    <script src="this_js_src.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
</head>
```

it works well like this on all mobile browsers and while developing use the rand number or something else to force the browser not to cache the code.. the cache in mobile browsers can be very frustrating